# Spring security: How I make to follow a link after logging and not going to the homepage

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm one of the developers of an application in what we have a login page to enter the dashboard. Inside the dashboard, there are different links that send you to other parts of the application.

The problem comes when you want to enter one of the internal links when you are no login. so in the browser you enter the address, put your credentials to continue to the web page, but instead, you are redirected to the dashboard.

The webpage I want to enter is:

```
http://localhost:8080/admin-ng/index.html#!/events/events/cd15fb84-d6b1-49ab-a28c-e5e07683907e/tools/editor
```

but after login always redirects to the dashboard:

```
http://localhost:8080/admin-ng/index.html#!/events/events
```

Then if I enter again the address works.

Also, I tried with a rest endpoint to call again the address after you log in, but it doesn't work, it is the same behavior.

I think it should be with the spring security config file. In how handle the requests after you are log in. I think it loses the rest of the information after the "#". What I can do?

Thanks

Comment: How did you get to the login page? Are your redirected to the login page when you try to enter a protected url (for example: `index.html#!/events/events/cd15fb84-d6b1-49ab-a28c-e5e07683907e/tools/editor`)? + we need to view your Spring Security configuration.

Comment: @HamdiDouss

Yes, you are redirected to the login page when you try to enter that address, is protected. 

Here is the spring security file, the project is open source so no worries. :) https://github.com/opencast/opencast/blob/develop/etc/security/mh_default_org.xml

Finally, if you want to try the app, you can do it in https://stable.opencast.org

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a success handler bean:

```
          .loginPage(LOGIN_FORM_URL)
          .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
          .successHandler(successHandler()) 
... 

@Bean
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
     SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("myredirectparam");
    successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("mydefaultredirect");
    return successHandler;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your [authentication success handler](https://github.com/opencast/opencast/blob/ceb51e5a42d21997f478b0d84ef674ab4fc310ee/modules/kernel/src/main/java/org/opencastproject/kernel/security/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.java), or your [entry point](https://github.com/opencast/opencast/blob/a5ef8620a777bb8db9ae56c972c6a826ba20b561/modules/kernel/src/main/java/org/opencastproject/kernel/security/DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.java).

I suggest to debug to figure out what is put in the `INITIAL_REQUEST_PATH` session attribute and if it is what you want.